# MX Lookup failed for outgoing email

Tags: windows-server-2008, mx-record

We use GMS (Gordano) mail server v3793 on a Win2008 box.

Since 4 days ago, outgoing mail has failed for all external domains, with POST log entries similar to the following:

```
DNS gmail.com - No address (-10)
MX lookup failed for gmail.com (89)
found 1 records for gmail.com using gmail.com
  1: gmail.com [216.58.206.101] 0
Resolved: gmail.com [216.58.206.101]
gmail.com failed to connect to gmail.com
```

I was originally using 156.154.70.1 as DNS server. Google and OpenDNS servers produce the same results.

Incoming mail appears OK.

[MX toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/supertool.aspx#) tells me Dns record not found from the Dns Record Published test.

A notable event is that server updates were applied about 36 hours before the problem started.

If there's any obvious solutions, please spell it out in obvious steps.

Thanks in advance.

### nslookup -type=mx -debug gmail.com

Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    222.222.67.208.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
ANSWERS:
->  222.222.67.208.in-addr.arpa
    name = resolver1.opendns.com
    ttl = 597210 (6 days 21 hours 53 mins 30 secs)
```

---

Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

---

Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 5,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    gmail.com, type = MX, class = IN
ANSWERS:
->  gmail.com
    MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
->  gmail.com
    MX preference = 40, mail exchanger = alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
->  gmail.com
    MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
->  gmail.com
    MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
->  gmail.com
    MX preference = 30, mail exchanger = alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of `nslookup -type=MX -debug gmail.com`?